# Swift Firebase Storage get all Download URL's of a specific child

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

Currently, I can fetch the **download url** by **file name** via firebase storage reference.

I would like to retrieve **all download URLS** in a specific child **without using a file name** and only using the last child name.

Simply adding every download url in a list/array

How can I accomplish this with my given reference.

```
func getDownloadURL() {
    
    let ref = Storage.storage().reference()
    
    let fileName = "Lessons_Lesson1_Class1.mp3"
    
    let starsRef = ref.child("Daily Meditations").child("Lessons").child("Lesson 1").child(fileName)
    

    // Fetch the download URL
    starsRef.downloadURL { url, error in
      if let error = error {
        // Handle any errors
        print(error)
      } else {
        // Get the download URL for 'Lessons_Lesson1_Class1.mp3'
        print(url)
      }
    }
   
    
}
```

[Firebase Refrence Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/create-reference)

Comment: Seems like you would want to use the list files API. https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/list-files

Comment: So i used list files but the result gives me the storage location and not the downloadURL.

Comment: Thank you @DougStevenson. I found a way by reviewing both documentation to achieve what I needed.

Comment: You have to call getDownloadUrl once for each file you find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to combine **List all files** and **Download URL** to achieve what I was trying to accomplish from the firebase documentation.

Here is the code:

```
func getDownloadURl() {
        
        let ref = Storage.storage().reference()
        
        let storageReference = ref.child("Lessons/Lesson 1")
        storageReference.listAll { (result, error) in
          if let error = error {
            print(error)
          }
        for item in result.items {
            //List storage reference
            let storageLocation = String(describing: item)
            let gsReference = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: storageLocation)
            
            // Fetch the download URL
            gsReference.downloadURL { url, error in
              if let error = error {
                // Handle any errors
                print(error)
              } else {
                // Get the download URL for each item storage location
                print(url!)
              }
            }
            
            
          }
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let stg = Storage.storage().reference()
let path = "Daily Meditations/Lessons/Lesson 1"

stg.child(path).listAll { (list, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print(error)
    } else {
        let inStorage = list.items.map({ $0.name })
        print(inStorage) // an array of file names in string format
    }
}
```

I assume spaces are allowed in path names since you're using them. To list all of the files in a path, use `listAll`. The method will return a `StorageListResult` object which I've named `list`.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasestorage/api/reference/Classes/StorageListResult

Comment: This only prints file names. Im sure there is a way to manipulate the file name to URL but I have already found a solution that works. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is using with VUE 2.6 and TS, here is my workaround

Imports

```
 import {
  getStorage,
  ref,
  getDownloadURL,
  listAll,
  StorageReference,
} from "firebase/storage";

async mounted(): Promise<void> {
 const storage = getStorage();
 const imageRefs = await listAll(ref(storage, "SOME BUCKET"))
  .then((refs) => {
    return refs.items;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Handle any errors
  });

(imageRefs as StorageReference[]).forEach((item) => {
  console.log(item);
  getDownloadURL(item).then((downloadURL) => {
    console.log(downloadURL);
    this.model.listFiles.push(downloadURL);
  });
});

console.log(imageRefs);
console.log(this.model.listFiles);
},
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).